# Bringing spring-data-jpa into a project causes Spring to stop processing @RequestMapping annotations

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

I have a Maven/Java project using Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE, which uses component scanning to pick up an @Controller with a number of @RequestMapping annotations and set up the appropriate endpoints.

As soon as I bring in a dependency on spring-data-jpa 1.4.1.RELEASE, the mappings stop being wired up (although the server still starts up without any errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you add **spring-data-jpa 1.4.1.RELEASE** to the pom.xml, it download **spring-orm-3.1.4** and others **3.1.4** dependencies. Those Dependencies are incompatible with **3.2.5** so you need do download manually.

To solve the problem you need to say maven to use the correct dependencies. ie. put in the pom.xml the next dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```